# if/else statement not registering if

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code seems to log the if statement as false, even though if I console.log the conditions it returns as true. Why is it doing that? (the code , that is not working is indicated by error not bypassing.)

```
function StaffMember(name,discountPercent){
        this.name = name;
        this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
    }

    function Stock(item){
        this.item = item;
    }

    //Global Variables
    var staffMembers = {};
    var sally = new StaffMember("Sally",0.05);
    staffMembers['sally'] = sally;
    var bob = new StaffMember("Bob",0.10);
    staffMembers['bob'] = bob;
    var me = new StaffMember("Aaron",0.20);
    staffMembers['me'] = me;
    //item variables

    var eggs = new Stock("Eggs");
    var milk = new Stock("Milk");
    var magazine = new Stock("Magazine");
    var chocolate = new Stock("Chocolate");


    //item Objects
    var Stock = {};
    Stock['eggs'] = eggs;
    Stock['milk'] = milk;
    Stock['magazine'] = magazine;
    Stock ['chocolate'] = chocolate;**


    var cashRegister = {
        total:0,
        lastTransactionAmount: 0,
        add: function(itemCost){
            this.total += (itemCost || 0);
            this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;
        },
        scan: function(item,quantity){
            switch (item){
            case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
            case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
            case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
            case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
            }
            return true;
        },
        voidLastTransaction : function(){
            this.total -= this.lastTransactionAmount;
            this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;
        },
        // Create a new method applyStaffDiscount here
        applyStaffDiscount : function(employee){
            this.total -= this.total*(employee.discountPercent);

        }

    };


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#target2').hide();
        $('#check').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var item = $('#item').val();
            var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
            var staff = $('#staff').val();

                    cashRegister.scan(item, quantity);
    //ERROR IN CODE NOT BYPASSING 
             if(item === Stock['item'] && quantity > 0) {
                    cashRegister.scan(item, quantity);


             }
    ///
             else {
                alert("This Item Does Not Exist!");         
             }
            if(staff.length > 0 && typeof staffMembers[staff] !='undefined'){
                cashRegister.applyStaffDiscount(staffMembers[staff]);
            }

            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            result.innerHTML = 'Your bill is ' + cashRegister.total.toFixed(2);


            $('#target2').fadeIn(5000)
             // .animate({opacity: 0.5}, 3000)
             .fadeOut(5000);
        });


        $('#target').submit(function(){
            var info = $(this).serializeJSON();
            console.log(info);      
            var data = JSON.parse('[info]');
            console.log(data);
            return false;
        });




    });
```

Comment: When your code runs, it is running in `$document.ready()`. At that time, is `Stock[`] fully populated and is `quantity > 0`? You should use Chrome's debugger to break on that line and step through to make sure. That may be why,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stock['item'] is going to return undefined because Stock['item'] is not declared. You declare Stock['milk'], Stock['magazine'],Stock['eggs'], and Stock['chocolate'], but not Stock['item']. If you were trying to use it as a variable, you should remove the quotes.

You are also overwriting your "Stock" function with a "Stock" object, which is not causing trouble right now but it could cause issues later down the line. You should rename those to be different if possible.

Try using `Stock[item] !== undefined && quantity > 0` in place of your current `if` expression

Comment: So what would be the way to rewrite that if statement to where it will return the else statement if the item inserted is not any of the objects

Comment: you can use ```Stock[item]``` without quotes, but you should compare it to undefined instead of ```item === Stock[item]```. Try ```Stock[item] !== undefined```

Comment: That worked thanks, I also found another way was to just to do ``` Stock['eggs'] = "eggs";```

Comment: No problem :) can you accept the answer if you don't need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your HTML or a working fiddle, but my guess is your if statement should be:

```
if(item === Stock[item] && quantity > 0) {
  cashRegister.scan(item, quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stock['item']` returns undefined as you're not calling it either with an object context like `obj.Stock()` or after using `bind` or `call`, so `this` is undefined. It's not returning anything either, so no assignment is made. I'm assuming `$('#item').val()` also. `$('#item')` is most likely null, triggering a runtime error and stopping your if sentence.